# Creating BYTE array struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, byte

I wanted to create an byte array in a struct in C of size 512, but the size of the structure is ending up being eight times that size. Could you please help as to how I'll make the required data structure.

This is my current code

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

typedef struct _ByteArray {

    BYTE *arr[512];
} __attribute__((__packed__))
JPEG;
```

Comment: You declare `arr` to be an array of 512 *pointers* to `BYTE`. On a 64-bit machine pointers are usually 64 bits, 8 bytes.

Comment: `BYTE *arr[512];` -> `BYTE arr[512];`

Comment: Thanks a million!!! It works!

Answer (score 1):

```
BYTE * arr[512];
 ^   ^  ^   ^
 |   |  |   |
 |   |  |  is an array of 512
 |   |  arr
 |  pointers to
BYTE
```

You have to change it to:

```
BYTE arr[512];
 ^    ^   ^
 |    |   |
 |    |  is an array of 512 
 |   arr 
BYTE
```

Since you want an array of bytes there is no need to make the struct packet because no padding bytes will be added.